Why are the words part1 and part2 not on the same vertical line?
The latex code is as below:
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document} 
part1  \\ 
\begin{flalign*} 
    a = b + c &\\ 
    d = e + f + g &\\ 
    h = i - j&
\end{flalign*} 
part2  \\ 
\begin{flalign*} 
    a = b + c \\ 
    d = e + f + g \\ 
    h = i - j
\end{flalign*} 

Why the words part1 and part2 are not on the same vertical line?


The first word in a paragraph is indented

... and don't abuse \ for line breaks outside of table-like material

Just as a test, you could add \usepackage{parskip} which replaces paragraph indentation with a vertical separation and you will see that part1 and 2 are positions equally.
